# flutter selectable text anchor position in rtl languages

Tags: flutter, dart, right-to-left

In flutter when I try using SelectableText widget with rtl languages, anchors behave wrong.

[image]

It's really unpredictable. you grab one of the anchors but the other one moves...

I tested this on both a real device and emulators.
I didn't manage to find anything about this on internet. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, wrapping a `Text` widget with `SelectionArea` widget worked...
It was a painful journey to find this. Hope it helps others.